# Cannot register IOS developer account on Appium Studio to add a phone

Tags: appium

On Appium Studio, registering a paid IOS developer account returns the error message below. I am registering with an Apple ID that has a paid Apple developer account and I am using an App Specific Password when registering. I have tried this on 3 different machines, 2 in the UK and 1 in USA.

```
Failed to add developer account with appleid: apple@XXXXXXXX.com and teamid: XXXXXXXXX reason: Bad response from server.
200: OK
Server says: Authentication Error. Xcode 7.3 or later required to continue developing with your Apple ID. (3019)
Please make sure you are not using a free account, as it is not supported.
```

[image: Appium Studio fails to register IOS developer account because of wrong XCode version]

### Environment

- Appium Studio version: ***22.1.8625***
- OS: ***Windows 10***

### Link to Appium logs

I have uploaded a copy of the Appium Studio log files to the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/charlbury/62eb07d1697a8f2f5fa0a74cbe509168

The first error mentioned in the logs that is not in the dialog box error message is `"ERROR  Initial CSR failed xign.client.execption.AppleServiceException: Bad response from server."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new version of the Appium Studio app has been released that addresses this issue and allows us to register the IOS developer account and to connect new iPhones.

The solution to this issue is to use the latest version of the Appium Studio app.

Answer (score -1):

Can you download security/app certificate and can ask dev to add testing system in there keystore certificate

Comment: Tried that. Downloaded the certificate from the apple developer account onto the machine running Appium. Double clicked the certificate file to install and installed in the Root certificate store for all users of the machine, but, still get the same error.

Comment: Have question around your error . 
1. What's xcode version you have in your system ? 
    -->Try to uninstall and reinstall from appStore 
2. Can you double check your team id it is case sensitive and did developer added your system in their keychain access . Sometime even you download and install certificate there is an issue with apple , that it don't identified that system . 
3. Can you try manually launch your application through appium from your localhost . (Might highlight issue from your webdriver.io file)?

Let me know above things

Comment: I don't have XCopde. This is a Windows 10 machine using Appium Studio. For the team id, Appium Studio retrieves this successfully when I enter the apple developer account username and app specific password, I don't specify it or modify it. I can't manually launch the app through Appium Studio as the key issue is that I cannot get the phone to connect to Appium Studio. I suspect you are referring to Appium and I am referring to Appium Studio https://digital.ai/continuous-testing/appium-studio.

Comment: Additionally, and most frustratingly, I cannot create an account on their Appium Studio forum because it never sends me the activation email (spam checked, many emails tried) so I cannot ask a question there. Does anyone have an account on https://appium.experitest.com/ and would they post a question for me or see if they can create an account and get an activation email?

Comment: So , onto windows machine even you wanted to login with proper credentials , apple won't allow you to do so . Understand in this way that apple wont' recognise your machine

`1. Xcode is not installed in your system(Appium Studio will also check for it internally environment set).`
`2. Apple won't be able to recognise your machine , obviously since its windows doesn't matter that you install your certificate and moreover even dev added your machine in keychain , it won't able to identify and provide access .`

Now comes solution part:

Comment: Now comes solution part:
`1. Try using mac machine and then try your setup ,it will work`
`2. Try using vmMachine and install mac image and then try it(Not Sure of this solution)

Comment: I already have this running on another windows machine, I just can't set up another machine to refine the and tidy up the installation. Appium Studio does not require XCode to be installed, it is designed to work this way as a link to operate a phone without XCode. I believe the error message reference to XCode refers to the version of XCode or XCode libraries on the Appium Studio servers that is used to link to the Apple Developer account.